# UTL_FILE and character set

Tags: oracle, plsql, character-encoding

I've been working on this thing for days and it's driving me crazy.
I have an oracle procedure that write a file using `UTL_FILE`.
I used to store my values as NVARCHAR2 and write my file using `UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE_NCHAR` procedure, and it wrote file in (what notepad++ consider as) UTF8.
The file is then used by another program, the problem is that said program read it using WE8MSWIN1252, and I can't change that, since it's legacy code.
So I tried to use `UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE` procedure instead, but the file was still considered as UTF8. 
I saw in oracle's documentation that `NVARCHAR2` used the national character set (mine is AL16UTF16), so I tried to use the `CONVERT` method like this:

```
CONVERT(whatIWantToWrite, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'AL16UTF16'))
```

and it raised the ORA-29298 Character set mismatch Exception.
I don't get it, my `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is AL16UTF16 why can't I convert it to WE8MSWIN1252 ?
Is there another way to write a file using WE8MSWIN1252 ?

Comment: When you changed from `put_line_nchar` to `put_line`, did you also change from `fopen_nchar` to `open`? Is `whatIWantToWrite` your `nvarchar2` column or a PL/SQL variable, and if the latter what data type is it?

Comment: You guessed right. I forgot to replace `fopen_nchar` with `fopen`.
Can't believe I spent so much time on this.
Anyway, Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be because you're still opening the file with `fopen_nchar`. If I do this:

```
create table t42(str nvarchar2(20));
insert into t42 values ('Hello');

declare
  file utl_file.file_type;
  l_str nvarchar2(20);
begin
  select str into l_str from t42;
  file := utl_file.fopen('<directory>', 'dummy.dat', 'w', 32767);
  utl_file.put_line(file, convert(l_str, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'AL16UTF16'));
  utl_file.fclose(file);
end;
/
```

... then I get a file containing `ä¡¥æ±¬`, which the Linux `file` command reports as `UTF-8 Unicode text`; Notepad++ shows `䡥汬` and says the file is 'ANSI as UTF-8'.

If I change the `fopen` to `fopen_nchar`:

```
  file := utl_file.fopen_nchar('CENSYS_EXPORT_DIR', 'dummy.dat', 'w', 32767);
```

... then I get `ORA-29298: Character set mismatch` and an empty file.

If I go back to `fopen` but change the PL/SQL variable to `varchar2`:

```
declare
  file utl_file.file_type;
  l_str varchar2(20);
begin
  select str into l_str from t42;
  file := utl_file.fopen('<directory>', 'dummy.dat', 'w', 32767);
  utl_file.put_line(file, convert(l_str, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'AL16UTF16'));
  utl_file.fclose(file);
end;
/
```

... then the file contains `Â¿Â¿` (in `vim`) and the file is reported as `ISO-8859 text`. But Notepad++ shows `߿` and says the file is ANSI.

Rather than using `convert`, which Oracle [discourages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions034.htm), you can bounce it through raw:

```
declare
  file utl_file.file_type;
  l_str varchar2(20);
begin
  select str into l_str from t42;
  file := utl_file.fopen('<directory>', 'dummy.dat', 'w', 32767);
  utl_file.put_line(file,
    utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_raw.convert(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_str),
      'ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8MSWIN1252', 'ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.UTF8')));
  utl_file.fclose(file);
end;
/
```

In Linux that shows as `Hello` and the file is reported as `ASCII text`; Notepad++ shows it as `Hello` as well, and again says the file is ANSI. I'm unclear if that gets you where you need to be... and you might need a different language and locale, of course.

But my database character set is AL32UTF8, and my national character set is AL16UTF16, so you might see different behaviour; if your database character set is WE8MSWIN1252 then the file will be created as that as well; from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70899):

> `UTL_FILE` expects that files opened by `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` in text mode
>   are encoded in the database character set. It expects that files
>   opened by `UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR` in text mode are encoded in the UTF8
>   character set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an option for you to convert the file afterwards it has been written to disc, e.g. with Java tool [Native-to-ASCII](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html) Converter.

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF8 my_text_file_utf.txt my_text_file.tmp
native2ascii -reverse -encoding windows-1252 my_text_file.tmp my_text_file_1252.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file`.

```
declare
  l_str varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  select str into l_str from t42;
  dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(to_clob(l_str), 'UTLDIR', 'file.txt', 2000);
END;
```

AL16UTF16(csid)=2000 WE8MSWIN1252(csid)=178 
To get `CSID`:

```
SELECT NLS_CHARSET_ID('WE8MSWIN1252') FROM DUAL;
```